# Bootstrap - navbar right is barely moving item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a header with links on the left side, but one link on the right hand side, when I try use navbar right it only moves it a small amount and barely does anything, this is my first time using bootstrap so any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>

@can('create', App\User::class)   
  </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Appointment</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item"   a href="{{url('addappointment')}}">Create Appointment</a>
@endcan

@can('delete', App\User::class)
      <a class="dropdown-item"  a href="{{url('deleteappointmentform')}}">Cancel Appointment</a>
            </div>
@endcan
</li>


            @can('create', App\User::class)
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Patient</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item"  a href="{{url('registerForm')}}">Register Patient</a>
@endcan 
@can('delete', App\User::class)         
      <a class="dropdown-item"  a href="{{url('deletePatientForm')}}">Remove Patient</a>
                  </div>

@endcan
  </li>
```

------------------This is the specific section i'm struggling with-----------------------

```
                          <ul class="nav-item dropdown navbar-right">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{Auth::user()->firstname}} {{Auth::user()->surname}}</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item"  a href="{{url('userdetails/'.Auth::user()->id)}}">My Details</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item"  a href="{{url('getLogout')}}">Log out</a>
</div>
</ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: class="pull-right" to your link, not your navabr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody wondering I found adding the class "navbar-toggler-right" fixed my problem